# "Missing Authentication Token" for OPTIONS preflight

Tags: aws-lambda, axios, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm using API Gateway provided by AWS and I have a serverless (framework) endpoint for delete method. The client is using Axios and is configured like this:

```js
  await Axios.delete(`${apiEndpoint}/todos/${todoId}`, {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${idToken}`
    }
  }).then..
```

This delete request is failing (403) apparently because of a failed OPTIONS preflight:

> {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}

What would be the best practices in this case?

1. Should I force/fix Axios client to send the Auth token in OPTIONS, and how to do that?
2. Or should I disable Auth for OPTIONS in the aws gateway endpoint, and how to do that?

```
DeleteTodo:
    handler: src/lambda/http/deleteTodo.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: delete
          path: todos/{todoId}
          authorizer: Auth
    iamRoleStatements:
```

**EDIT**: added `cors: true` didn't create OPTIONS for todos/{todoId} at AWS Gateway, maybe this is a bug with serverless-framework? (I had to explicitly define an endpoint for OPTIONS, which is not ok.

```
Framework Core: 1.60.1
Plugin: 3.2.6
SDK: 2.2.1
Components Core: 1.1.2
Components CLI: 1.4.0
```

Comment: I work on my personal project with AWS, serverless framework, and resolved a  MissingAuthenticationToken and CQRS issue. I did modify serverless.yml and response headers. I hope this can help, https://ijianhuang.wordpress.com/2019/12/31/what-is-http-preflight-request-how-to-fix-cors-between-aws-cloud-front-and-website/.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. I had the very same issue with Axios. All prefight requests must be anonymous. See also [this ticket](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63937) in Tomcat. So does the spec require it and browsers won't send any auth header regardless what you do.

Comment: thanks @Michael-O, I managed to fix this by creating an endpoint for OPTIONS pointing to the same lambda for deleteTodo, far from ideal, still researching serverless-framework for that, let me know if you have any more insights!

Comment: @martin, please note that a preflight options request ist not a regular optíons request.  You have to differentiate here. Look at the filter in Tomcat and you'll notice. At best, don't try to solve this if there is a solution somewhere else.